# Vectors Geometry question

Tags: vector-spaces

Find the equation of the line going through the point $(2,-3,4)$ ,and which is parralel to the plane $ x+2y + 2z = 13$

So I tried this: the normal of the plane is $(1,2,2)$, random point on the line is $(x,y,z)$, so direciton vector is $(x-2,y+3,z-4)$. We'll require $(x-2,y+3,z-4)\cdot (1,2,2) = 0$. This yields $x-2y+2z -4 =0$ which is a plane formula not a line formula.

Comment: Its fine since you there are infinitely many lines passing thru a point and being parallel to a given plane

Comment: yeah but you need a line eqation not plane eqation

Comment: Just pick one line lying on the plane. i.e. choose one more point in the plane and join the two. Thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is parallel to the plane $\;\iff\;$ it is normal to the plane's normal, thus you need a direction vector $\;(x,y,z)\;$ s.t.

$$(x,y,z)\cdot (1,2,2)=0\iff x+2y+2z=0$$

so for example $\;(x,y,z)=(2,0,-1)\;$, and thus one line as wanted is, say

$$(2,-3,4)+t(2,0,-1)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Your result only shows that the set of **all** lines as wanted is a plane...

Comment: yeah it makes sense..

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get a plane is because the line passing through $(2,-3,4)$ and parallel to $x+2y+2z=13$ is not unique. Any line on the plane $x−2y+2z−4=0$ is a solution.